# How to reduce the space between two lines of text in a circle

Tags: html, css

I got a circle with 2 lines of text.
The first says: P
the second says: Publications.

The space between them is currently too big. Is there a way to make the space smaller ?

```css
.circle1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  background: #73B7DB;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 105px;
  padding-top:5px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.Capital {
  margin: 0px 0 0px 0;
  line-height:70px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight:ligter;
}
.text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle1">
  <h2 class="Capital">P</h2>
  <span class="text">Publications</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a negativ `margin`. Like `margin: 0px 0 -10px 0` for `.Capital`.

```css
.circle1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  background: #73B7DB;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 105px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.Capital {
  margin: 0px 0 -10px 0;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: ligter;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle1">
  <h2 class="Capital">P</h2>
  <span class="text">Publications</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line-height of the .Capital class to a smaller value will do just that.

```
.Capital {
    margin: 10px 0 0px 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: ligter;
}
```

That will make it look more centred as well.

Comment: I prefer this approach than using negative margins (which may cause other side effects such as an element space that didn't got covered because the said element is "up" by a negative margin). Using a negative margins means that there may be some CSS mistakes elsewhere.